# Cannot build Unity WebGL project from script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a problem with building Unity Project on WebGL target. This only appeares when I'm trying to build from script. When I build it from Unity project builds fine.
I think it can also be important, I'm running this methot from powershell script

PS Script:

```
$unityPath = "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe"
$unityParameters = "-batchmode -projectPath `"$($repo)\`" -username USERNAME -password PASS -executeMethod `"BuildScript.PerformBuild`""
$buildProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $unityPath -ArgumentList $unityParameters -Wait -PassThru
```

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;

public class BuildScript
{
     public static void PerformBuild()
     {
         var projectName = "scene_1";
         Debug.Log("### BUILDING ###");
         EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTargetGroup.WebGL, BuildTarget.WebGL);
         var report = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(
             new[] {$"Assets/Scenes/{projectName}.unity"}, 
             $"Build/Win/{projectName}.exe", 
             BuildTarget.WebGL,
             BuildOptions.None);
         
         Debug.Log("###   DONE   ###");
 
         Debug.Log(report);
         EditorApplication.Exit(1);
     }
}
```

Error I get in report:

> Switching to WebGL:WebGLSupport is disabled
>
> ...
>
> DisplayProgressNotification: Build Failed Error building player
>
> Error building player because build target was unsupported

Comment: You might try passing `-buildTarget WebGL` on the command line. That's what we do.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. There are rules for posting and you've done pretty good compared to some. However, the tag powershell seems extremely out of place. Please tag your post accordingly and also read through the topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RetiredNinja
I've added `-buildTarget WebGL` to command line, but nothing changes. I also tried to run my cs script from unity, and it worked fine, so it must be something with my script.
@DougMaurer
I've removed powershell tag from question. Sorry about that

Comment: There's a note in the documentation for [SwitchActiveBuildTarget](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget.html) that says it is not available in batch mode and that you should use the command line switch only. *shrug*

Comment: @RetiredNinja for me `SwitchActiveBuildTarget` works perfectly fine without `-buildTarget WebGL` and everything works from his code. Maybe Unity cannot find WebGL as a Unity  Package

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak I would expect it to work as well since the scripts are recompiled when building the player anyway but we set it from the command line and skip it in batch mode. Our script is more complicated though with asset bundle building and such and has evolved over many Unity versions so it's probably more of a "don't change what isn't broken" situation over the "right" way to do things. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have WebGL support installed at eg: `C:\Program Files\Unity\2020.1.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport`

This error `Switching to WebGL:WebGLSupport is disabled` says that WebGLSupport is probably missing from you Unity installation.

Please double check that you are using the same installation of Unity in the script and in the Editor. You can check your path in UnityHub via `Show in Explorer` option
[image]

Comment: Good call! I thought about this but assumed it was the same installation being used to build in the editor and with the script.